# Combobox moving resources to disk

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedText = "Anaheim" Then Dim finalpath As String = "C:\hockey055f\data\model\ice0.png"
    My.Resources.anaice.Save("C:\hockey055f\data\model\ice0.png")
    MsgBox("Installed!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Installed by GoLeafsGo")

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedText = "Boston" Then If System.IO.File.Exists("c:\hockey055f\data\model\ice0.png") Then 
    System.IO.File.Delete("c:\hockey055f\data\model\ice0.png")
    My.Resources.bosice.Save("C:\hockey055f\data\model\ice0.png")
    MsgBox("Installed!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Installed by GoLeafsGo")
End Sub
```

This is my code. I am trying to make it so that when an item is selected by the user in the combobox and the user presses the button, the file will transfer from my resources to the directory shown above. When I click on the first value (Anaheim), the file "anaice.png" is transferred, but then the "bosice.png" from the (Boston) value is put in and overwrites the the other image. Help please!

Comment: So it should be instead saved as…?

Comment: And please indent and avoid putting as much as possible on one line. It’s much harder to understand.

Comment: should be saved as the (Anaheim) value which represents anaice.png

Comment: It's totally unclear your problem to me

Comment: Both operations are saving to the same file `C:\hockey055f\data\model\ice0.png`.  IF you dont want them over replace each other use another name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, But I don't know if this is what you want:

```
private finalpath As String = "C:\hockey055f\data\model\ice0.png"
private res = nothing

private sub ComboBox_Selectedindexchanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
handles ComboBox1.Selectedindexchanged

    Select case sender.Selectedindex

        case is 0:res= My.Resources.anaice
        case is 1:res= My.Resources.bosice
        case else
             msgbox ("select case is out of range")

    end select

end sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click

    try:io.File.Delete(finalpath):catch:end try
    res.Save(finalpath)

    MsgBox("Installed!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Installed by GoLeafsGo")

End Sub
```

PS: Code is written on the fly maybe it contains syntax error(s).

Comment: Thanks so much! Just had to add an "=" after Case is to get it to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2898546 you're welcome I'm glad to help, please mark the answer as accepted if question is resolved